# How to convert a Table to a DataStream containing array types (Flink)?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-table-api

I have issues concerning the table-api of Flink (1.13+). I have a POJO containing several fields, one of them being:

```
List<String> my_list;
```

I create my table using the following declaration for this field:

```
"CREATE TABLE my_table (
   ...
   my_list ARRAY<STRING>,
   ...
)"
```

When I try to convert my table to DataStream using the toRetractStream[MY_POJO] method after, I got the following error:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Column types of query
> result and sink for unregistered table do not match.
>
> Cause: Incompatible types for sink column 'my_list' at position 11.
> Query schema: [..., my_list: ARRAY, ...] Sink schema:  [...,
> my_list: RAW('java.util.List', ?), ...]

I would like to avoid mapping every fields by hand and keep the code clean, is there a solution to handle this kind of data types ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to try out the new API methods `from/toDataStream` and `from/toChangelogStream`. Those support [all kinds of classes and data types](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/#examples-for-todatastream).

`toDataStream` supports also mapping to POJOs with `List` members.

Comment: Not working for me, with new API I have the same issue

Comment: @Niko Maybe you can share an example with us? Or send it to my via Flink's Slack channel. It should work.

Comment: I already forget what was my exact problem I have several complex fields and finally I used UDF's to figure it out. I asked about one of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73321239/unable-to-decode-avro-data-from-kafka-with-avro-schema). How I can find Flink Slack ?

Comment: Great that you could find a solution. Slack can be found here: https://flink.apache.org/community.html#slack